# Wheredoesnthave relation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've a problem doing a query using Eloquent/Laravel.

This is my model:
A request has ZERO or multiple offers. An offer can be hide (it's an attribute set on the offer).

What I need to do is to retrieve all requests that either have or don't have offers. BUT, if there's an offer associated, the offer needs to have the attribute hide=false.

I've tried the following, but doesn't seem to work.

```
$requests = Request::whereDoesntHave('offers', function ($query) use ($hideStatus) {
   $query->where('hide', true);
})->get();
```

I think it's returning to me only requests that don't have offers at all.

Any idea?

FYI, I've Laravel 5.4

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I think you should write 2 separate queries where 1 will filter data of offer with hide=false and the other query where offer does not exist

Comment: Yea....I think that with the reply of @Saumini below, we're on the good track, but still not 100% there..maybe some syntax errors..

Answer (score 0):

Check below query. I didn't test the query, wrote it with the knowledge I have.

```
$requests = Request::whereHas('offers', function ($query) {
                    $query->where('hide', false);
                })
                ->orDoesntHave('offers')
                ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this does not work. I get the error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::orDoesntHave().

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your replies. "orDoesntHave" does not work. It seems instead that the following works:

```
$requests = Request::whereHas('offers', function ($query) {
                $query->where('hide', false);
            })
            ->doesntHave('offers', 'or')
            ->get();
```